Why do I have files named __azurite_db_blob__.json and similar in my solution folder?
I have been using azurite for a while now in my ASPNET Core project. I recently updated azurite and Azure Storage Explorer, and since I did that I have had some files appear in my solution folder. Specifically, the files are:
__azurite_db_table__.json
__azurite_db_blob__.json
__azurite_db_blob_extent__.json
__azurite_db_queue__.json
__azurite_db_queue_extent__.json

I've tried googling to find out what these files are but can't find anything concrete. My current theory is that this is a coincidence - perhaps I recently started Azurite from my solution folder and this is the default location for these files? If that's the case then it's pure chance that I've never done this before.
Can anyone give me an explanation? I can gitignore them, but really I want to know what they are and if I can just delete them.
